# read and display the xml file details in codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I have a xml file as shown below.

How can I read and display the name and size in a view with help of a controller?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QCARConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="qcar_config.xsd">
  <Tracking>
    <ImageTarget name="news_opera_house" size="1200.000000 755.705811" />
    <ImageTarget name="news_istambul" size="700.000000 415.091461" />
  </Tracking>
</QCARConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SimpleXML library I use to make this easier for you. Unzip it to your /application/libraries folder

```
//Load SimpleXML library
$this->load->library('simplexml');
$xmlData = $this->simplexml->xml_parse($xml); //where $xml is your xml to parse

var_dump($xmlData); //You should see an multi dimensional array for each node
```

Just loop through the appropriate arrays to access the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display size and name on your view file.First you will have to get name and size on your controller.

```
public function index(){

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QCARConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="qcar_config.xsd">
  <Tracking>
    <ImageTarget name="news_opera_house" size="1200.000000 755.705811" />
    <ImageTarget name="news_istambul" size="700.000000 415.091461" />
  </Tracking>
</QCARConfig>';

$xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

 foreach ($xmlcont as $value) {
    $val = $value->ImageTarget;
    foreach ($val as $key) {
        //echo $key['size']."<br/>";
        //echo $key['name']."<br/>";
       $data = array('size' => $key['size'],'name' => $key['name'] );
       $this->load->view('main_view', $data); //passing value to view

    }

 }

}
```

After this you can simply get the values in `view` by printing the `$data`

```
<?php print_r($data);?>
```